# showModalBottomSheet is show, but showBottomSheet not show

Tags: android, flutter

android studio 3.6

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: new Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY_DARK)));
    return new Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                        right: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                        bottom: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
                    child: new Column(children: [
                      new Padding(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsets.only(top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
                          child: _createProfileContainer(context)),
```

...

```
  Widget _createProfileContainer(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _showBottomSheetInvoice(context);
        },
        child:
```

...

```
void _showBottomSheetInvoice(BuildContext context) {
    _logger.d("_showBottomSheetInvoice: ");
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new Container(
              color: new Color(Constants.BOTTOM_SHEET_BG),
              child:
```

As result the **showModalBottomSheet** success show. But I need to show **showBottomSheet**. I replace **showModalBottomSheet** by **showBottomSheet**. And as result the **showBottomSheet** not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `_scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet` 
code snippet

```
void _showBottomSheetInvoice(BuildContext context) {        
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet((BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
          child: Column(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  Widget _createProfileContainer(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _showBottomSheetInvoice(context);
        },
        child: Text("click"));
  }

  void _showBottomSheetInvoice(BuildContext context) {
    //_logger.d("_showBottomSheetInvoice: ");
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet((BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text(
                'Persistent header for bottom bar!',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              )),
          Text(
            'Then here there will likely be some other content '
            'which will be displayed within the bottom bar',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ],
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.blue));
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 4, bottom: 4),
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                          child: _createProfileContainer(context)),
                    ])))));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```